# left join with external query in query-builder

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I need to create that query in query builder

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.parent_id = table2.id OR table1.id = table2.id) WHERE table2.id IS NULL;
```

I already've got

```
$er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->leftJoin('Bundle2:table2', 'n')
                    ->where('p.parent = n.id')
                    ->andWhere('p.id = n.id');
```

but don't know how to add external WHERE to query ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('t1')
      ->leftJoin('t1.table2', 't2')
      ->where('t1.parent = t2.id OR t1.id = t2.id')
      ->andWhere('t2.id IS NULL')
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult();
```